# How specify generate path for annotationProcessPath in kotlin-maven-plugin?

Tags: kotlin, hibernate-mapping, kapt, kotlin-maven-plugin

I am using hibernate-jpamodelgen as static jpa generator in kotlin-maven-plugin.
However it can't find original classes.

```
cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class Type
```

After inspection, I found that in that case entities generated in generated-source/kapt.
All other classes generated in kaptStubs directory.
Without kapt it works fine.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kapt</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>kapt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <annotationProcessorPath>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                                <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
                            </annotationProcessorPath>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Output option doesn't work.
How could I change the output directory to consistency?

Thank you, Irina

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue: the generated classes by cannot find the original hibernate-jpamodelgen.